# Unable to install SQL Server 2014 Express Management Tools because of Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell?

Tags: sql-server, management-studio-express

I could not install SQL Server 2014 Express Management Tools and its Management Studio and when I checked Summary log file I encountered with this text which I could not understand:

Detailed results:

```
 Feature:    Management Tools - Complete
 Status:    Failed: see logs for details

 Reason for failure:  An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.

 Next Step:  Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.

 Component name:          Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell
 Component error code:    1651
 Component log file:      C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20180726_134032\VSShell_Cpu32_1.log

Error description:  Windows Installer does not permit updating of managed advertised products. At least one feature of the product must be installed before applying the update.
```

Now I could not find any place to download "MS Visual Studio 2010 Shell".

For your info I had VS studio 2010 express before on my machine but I uninstalled it.

Please help me how I can solve the problem.

Comment: SSMS is now a separate download. The latest version is 17.8.1 which you can download from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017). It doesn't depend on the VS 2010 shell

Comment: Have you looked in the "Component log file" that's mentioned in the error message? Does that tell you anything??

Comment: You could also check out the newest SSMS (v17) - it's now available separately, and it's free to use with any version of SQL Server - including Express. Get it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017